# how to fill a column based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Value":[1,4,2,1,2,1,2,2],'type':['S','C','L','C','C','S','L','S'],'exit_value':[8,'','','','',2,'','1']})

    Value   type    exit_value
0   1          S    8
1   4          C    
2   2          L    
3   1          C    
4   2          C    
5   1          S    2
6   2          L    
7   2          S    1
```

I wish to have the following results:

```
    Value   type    exit_value
0   1          S    8
1   4          C    8
2   2          L    8
3   1          C    
4   2          C    
5   1          S    2
6   2          L    2
7   2          S    1
```

The logic: in each type S I have an exit_value and that value should be fill all the way to the first L type.

What have I tried?
I can get the indexes of each type S and the indexes of each type L and iterate from S to L and provide the value I had in index S but I sense that this solution is overdoing.

Comment: Your last `type S` has no `exit_value`.

Comment: @Michael Szczesny thanks for spotting. Fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC first select the rows with `S` and `L`, `groupby` and `transform` on `first`, assign to column and finally compare with `where`:

```
s = df[df["type"].isin(["S", "L"])]

df["exit_value"] = s.groupby(s["type"].eq("S").cumsum())["exit_value"].transform("first")

print (df.ffill().where(df.ffill()==df.bfill()))

   Value type exit_value
0      1    S          8
1      4    C          8
2      2    L          8
3      1    C        NaN
4      2    C        NaN
5      1    S          2
6      2    L          2
7      2    S          1
```

Comment: thank you! wonder if you can verbally explain this line: s["type"].eq("S").cumsum()  what are you achieving with this? Thanks again!

Comment: It checks for presence of `S` which returns a boolean series, and `cumsum` would turn it into a grouping. Try print out `s["type"].eq("S").cumsum()`.

Comment: oh ok, got it. Learned something new today.